# Split string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, split

I have below table as a sample value:

```
CREATE TABLE #T(COl1 VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES('1) Elevated BMI  2) Elevated cholesterol  3) Deficient vitamin D level  4) No structured exercise  5) Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration.  6) Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP  7) Suboptimal blood glucose')

select * From #T
```

I want the output to be below as separate rows, how do I write the query?

```
Elevated BMI
Elevated cholesterol
Deficient vitamin D level
No structured exercise
Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration.
Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP
Suboptimal blood glucose
```

Below is what I was able to achieve:

```
select value From #T
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COl1, ')')

1
 Elevated BMI  2
 Elevated cholesterol  3
 Deficient vitamin D level  4
 No structured exercise  5
 Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration.  6
 Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP  7
 Suboptimal blood glucose
```

Comment: There are many split string functions people have created you can search on here for one of those and split by the 2 spaces separating each line item when calling the function.  You will have to do some substring functions to remove the number and the )

Comment: So, what is your question here? All you state is you want, but not what you are asking. Have you made an attempt to solve the problem? What was the difficulty you were having solving the problem?

Comment: @ThomA of course - what should be the query to achieve it.

Comment: You write the query by doing research, and then using your findings to write the appropriate T-SQL.

Comment: Agree, see what i was able to achieve above.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: By far the best solution would be to fix the design here. Storing delimited data list violates 1NF and is nothing short of dreadful to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I note that every numbered point in your data is preceded by two spaces. You can leverage this fact to your advantage:

```
select value
from T
cross apply String_Split(Replace(COl1, '  ','~'), '~');
```

See [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/qkLS0hSW)

Answer (score 1):

data

```
CREATE TABLE #T(COl1 VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES('1) Elevated BMI  2) Elevated cholesterol  3) Deficient vitamin D level  4) No structured exercise  5) Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration.  6) Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP  7) Suboptimal blood glucose')

select * From #T
```

You can use combination of pivot and unpivot to get the desired result:

```
;   
with c as(
select COl1
      ,REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (value, '0', ''),
'1', ''),
'2', ''),
'3', ''),
'4', ''),
'5', ''),
'6', ''),
'7', ''),
'8', ''),
'9', '') value
      ,row_number() over(partition by COl1 order by (select null)) as rn
from #T
cross apply string_split(COl1, ')') as bk
)

select indicatorname,
  indicatorvalue
from (
select --COl1
    
      [2]
      ,[3]
      ,[4]
      ,[5]
      ,[6]
      ,[7]
from c
pivot(
    max(value)
    for rn in( [2],[3],[4],[5],[6] ,[7])  
) as pvt
) AS A
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in (  
      [2]
      ,[3]
      ,[4]
      ,[5]
      ,[6]
      ,[7])
) unpiv
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3tw_2OxW)

Answer (score 0):

[`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a built in function. In the most recent version it also optionally returns an ordinal which we can leverage here:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (COl1 VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('1) Elevated BMI  2) Elevated cholesterol  3) Deficient vitamin D level  4) No structured exercise  5) Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration.  6) Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP  7) Suboptimal blood glucose')

SELECT TRIM(LEFT(s.value,LEN(value)-2)) AS Value, s.ordinal-1 AS Ordinal
  FROM @T
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COl1,')', 1) s
 WHERE LEN(s.value) > 2;
```

| Value | Ordinal |
| --- | --- |
| Elevated BMI | 1 |
| Elevated cholesterol | 2 |
| Deficient vitamin D level | 3 |
| No structured exercise | 4 |
| Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration. | 5 |
| Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP | 6 |
| Suboptimal blood gluco | 7 |

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select id,nn.value as partN
  ,trim(
   case when lead(value)over(partition by id order by value) is not null then
     substring(col1,charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),' '+col1)
      ,charindex(concat(lead(value)over(partition by id order by value),')')
          ,' '+col1) -charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),' '+col1) 
          )
   else substring(col1,charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1)
                   ,len(col1)-charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),' '+col1)+1)
   end) x
from generate_series(1,20) nn
inner join #T on charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1)>0
order by id,value
```

Source data

| id | COl1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1) Elevated BMI 2) Elevated cholesterol 3) Deficient vitamin D level 4) No structured exercise 5) Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration. 6) Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP 7) Suboptimal blood glucose |
| 2 | 1) One 3) Three 4)Four 5) Five 6)Six 7)Seven 8)Eight 9)Nine 10)ten 11)eleven 12)twelve |

Output

| id | partN | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1) Elevated BMI |
| 1 | 2 | 2) Elevated cholesterol |
| 1 | 3 | 3) Deficient vitamin D level |
| 1 | 4 | 4) No structured exercise |
| 1 | 5 | 5) Elevated alcohol intake with mild fatty liver infiltration. |
| 1 | 6 | 6) Elevated CK, Ferritin and high-sensitive CRP |
| 1 | 7 | 7) Suboptimal blood glucose |
| 2 | 1 | 1) One |
| 2 | 3 | 3) Three |
| 2 | 4 | 4)Four |
| 2 | 5 | 5) Five |
| 2 | 6 | 6)Six |
| 2 | 7 | 7)Seven |
| 2 | 8 | 8)Eight |
| 2 | 9 | 9)Nine |
| 2 | 10 | 10)ten |
| 2 | 11 | 11)eleven |
| 2 | 12 | 12)twelve |

Or without `generate_series`

```
select id,nn.value as partN
  ,trim(
   case when lead(value)over(partition by id order by value) is not null then
     substring(col1,charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1)
      ,charindex(concat(lead(value)over(partition by id order by value),')')
          ,col1) -charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1) 
          )
   else substring(col1,charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1)
                      ,len(col1)-charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1)+1)
   end) x
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
           ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
     )nn(value)
inner join #T on charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),col1)>0
order by id,value
```

With CTE

```
with t as(
select id,nn.value as partN,charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),' '+col1) posN ,col1
from generate_series(1,20) nn
inner join #T on charindex(concat(' ',value,')'),' '+col1)>0
)
select id,partN --,posN
  ,trim(
   case when lead(posN)over(partition by id order by partN) is not null then
     substring(col1,posN ,lead(posN)over(partition by id order by partN)-posN-1 )
   else substring(col1,posN,len(col1)-posN+1)
   end) x
from t
order by id,partN
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/73jCXx9h)